# c++ calling method from outside of a class

Tags: c++, oop, class, methods

Ok, I reduced my problem to something that looks really silly but I simply cannot understand why this:

```
#include <iostream>
class ABC{
public:
    void Print() { std::cout<<"ABC_TEST!\n"; }
};

int main(){
    Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me: error: identifier "Print" is undefined
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this :

```
#include <iostream>
class ABC{
public:
    void Print() { std::cout<<"ABC_TEST!\n"; }
};

int main(){
    ABC abc;
    abc.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

You need to create an object of type `ABC` before you can call instance methods(or member functions which are not static)

Alternatively, `Print()` can be a static function and you will be able to call it with the `::` operator.

```
class ABC {
   public:
     static void Print() { std::cout << "ABC_TEST\n"; }
};

int main()
{
   ABC::Print();
   return 0;
}
```

Above all else, `Print()` can also be a global function:

```
void Print()
{
   std::cout << "ABC_TEST\n" ;
}

int main()
{
   Print();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would I call a global function from a class that includes a function with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

`Print()` is a member function of `ABC`, so you can only call it on an instance of `ABC`:

```
ABC abc;
abc.Print();
```

As a completely unrelated note, in C++ a return with value `0` is implied, so it is not necessary to write `return 0`.

Comment: So, if I'd like to perform this kind of a simple operation, should I simply put Print() outside of my class and that's it?

Comment: @SimonRighley basically, yes. Another option is to make it a static function of `ABC`, in which case you don't need an instance, but the call syntax is `ABC::Print()`.

Answer (score 1):

`Print()` is a *member function* of your ABC class, you need an object to invoke it on:

```
int main()
{
    ABC abc; // This creates an instance of ABC

    abc.Print();
//  ^^^^
//  This invokes member function `Print()` on the object abc.

    return 0;
}
```

The address of `abc` will be passed as an implicit first parameter to function `Print()`: that parameter will be accessible inside of `Print()` (more generally, inside an invoked member function) as the `this` pointer.

If you try calling `Print()` as if it were a non-member, free function, no implicit `this` pointer would be passed, and it makes sense that the compiler complains about it.

If you want to be able to invoke `Print()` the way you did, you should make it a non-member function:

```
void Print() { std::cout<<"ABC_TEST!\n"; }

int main()
{
    Print(); // This is fine now!
}
```